# Jquery Not Executing, works fine on JSfiddle

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get this fadein/fadeout effect to work, swapping one div for another. I cannot seem to get it to work. It works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3XwZv/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var fadeinBox = $("#box2");
var fadeoutBox = $("#box1");

function fade() {
fadeinBox.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);
fadeoutBox.stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    var temp = fadeinBox;
    fadeinBox = fadeoutBox;
    fadeoutBox = temp;
    setTimeout(fade, 1000);
});
}

fade();

</script>
```

**Here are the styles**

```
<style>

.box {
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

#wrapper {position: relative;}

#box1 {background-color: #F00;}
#box2 {background-color: #00F;  display: none;}

</style>
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="box1" class="box">This box is our main div</div>


<div id="box2" class="box">This box fades in as other div fades out</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the js part placed? After of before the html?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your jQuery in a **[document ready call](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** or put the JS at the end of the document. You're trying to execute it on elements that don't exist yet. jsFiddle defaults to adding your code inside a window.load call (see the options in the upper left corner of jsFiddle).

Ex:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var fadeinBox = $("#box2");
    var fadeoutBox = $("#box1");
    function fade() {
        fadeinBox.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
        fadeoutBox.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
            var temp = fadeinBox;
            fadeinBox = fadeoutBox;
            fadeoutBox = temp;
            setTimeout(fade, 1000);
        });
    }
    fade();
});
```

Comment: You've included jQuery UI in your page, not jQuery. Change the URL to `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Ahh. got it. Thanks so much to the both of you for your help!